# Downloading lots of files asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, rust, download

(Original code is taken from  http://patshaughnessy.net/2020/1/20/downloading-100000-files-using-async-rust )

I have some code to download images concurrently using Rust, however, I'm not sure how to implement 2 things. The first, rate limiting, to avoid 429s. I tried using `std::thread::sleep`, however, this does not work as I would expect. (The same thing happens with tokio::time::sleep) (I did not write the original code, and am new to async rust, so I am unsure of the specifics of how and when the code runs.).

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let paths: Vec<String> = read_lines("links.txt")?;
    let fetches = futures::stream::iter(
    paths.into_iter().map(|path| {
        async move {
            let a = path.split('/').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
            let file_name = a.last().unwrap();
            tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
            match reqwest::get(&path).await {
                Ok(resp) => {
                    if resp.status().as_u16() != 200 {
                        println!("failed to download");
                        println!("{}", path);
                    };
                    match resp.bytes().await {
                        Ok(bytes) => {
                            //println!("RESPONSE: {} bytes from {}", (bytes.len()), path);
                            write(format!("downloads/{}", file_name), bytes).unwrap();
                        }
                        Err(_) => println!("ERROR reading {}", path),
                    }
                }
                Err(_) => println!("ERROR downloading {}", path),
            }
        }
    })
    ).buffer_unordered(200).collect::<Vec<()>>();
    fetches.await;
    Ok(())
}
```

Secondly, I want to have a list of a list of links which were "rate limited" (returned a 429 status), and print that once all other files are finished downloading. My attempt, and resulting compiler error message are as follows:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut failed: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let paths: Vec<String> = read_lines("links.txt")?;
    let fetches = futures::stream::iter(
    paths.into_iter().map(|path| {
        async move {
            let a = path.split('/').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
            let file_name = a.last().unwrap();
            match reqwest::get(&path).await {
                Ok(resp) => {
                    if resp.status().as_u16() != 200 {
                        println!("failed to download {}", path);
                        failed.push(path);
                        return // To avoid downloading the file, which will not contain what we want.
                    };
                    match resp.bytes().await {
                        Ok(bytes) => {
                            //println!("RESPONSE: {} bytes from {}", (bytes.len()), path);
                            write(format!("downloads/{}", file_name), bytes).unwrap();
                        }
                        Err(_) => println!("ERROR reading {}", path),
                    }
                }
                Err(_) => println!("ERROR downloading {}", path),
            }
        }
    })
    ).buffer_unordered(200).collect::<Vec<()>>();
    fetches.await;
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `failed`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:28:20
   |
24 |       let mut failed: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
   |           ---------- captured outer variable
...
28 |           async move {
   |  ____________________^
29 | |             let a = path.split('/').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
30 | |             let file_name = a.last().unwrap();
31 | |             match reqwest::get(&path).await {
...  |
35 | |                         failed.push(path);
   | |                         ------
   | |                         |
   | |                         move occurs because `failed` has type `Vec<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   | |                         move occurs due to use in generator
...  |
47 | |             }
48 | |         }
   | |_________^ move out of `failed` occurs here
```

How can I do this?

Comment: For your first question, I don't know if 200 is too large for the `buffer_unordered` function. Have you tried with a smaller value, like 8, that was used in the source [post](http://patshaughnessy.net/2020/1/20/downloading-100000-files-using-async-rust) you referred to.

Comment: You must not use blocking functions within an async function. Instead of `std::thread::sleep` use `tokio::time::sleep`